# Generate "serial" code with specific pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I'm trying to accomplish is that for example if I have 0000-0000-0000-0000, then I'd like to have for example 2nd code letters only and/or specific letters that I could set myself as a preset such as: 2KS8-LMAO-8XG2-48SY. Right now I have the code to replace each string with random letter/number that I've written in html.

```
function randomised(len) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
}

function randomiseString(str){
    var charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var str = str.replace(/[^-]/g,function() {
        var a = charSet[randomised(charSet.length)].toUpperCase();
        return a;
    });
    return str;
}

$('.combination').text(function(i,t){
    return randomiseString(t);
});
```

--

```
<b>Random Combination:</b> <span class="combination">0000-0000-0000-0000</span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now every "row?" is random, however I'd like to have a specific row to be for example letters only. 5W1C-(ASDF)-B82I-S8KL

Comment: Just to be a pedant, that's Javascript. Html is the page which contains (or references) the Javascript.

Comment: It's just something I'm trying to learn right now, interacting Javascript with HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to somehow pass in a pattern that you wanted it to match. Then separate your str_replace into multiple parts. So, if you wanted to replace a character you would use one set of characters, with a letter you would use a different set of characters. Something like this perhaps:

```
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var nums = "0123456789"
str.replace(/[0-9]/g, function () {
    return nums[randomised(nums.length()];
}
str.replace(/[a-z]/g, function () {
    return chars[randomised(chars.length()].toUpperCase();
}
```

In this case, whatever `str` holds will be the pattern, you could then define patterns. Such as `0000-aaaa-0000-aaaa` each time you run the script, the pattern will remain the same (i.e. 4 numbers, 4 letters, etc)